Connecting Events to Contributions
My org is running a big event and that event is going to have an entry/ticket fee, which we'd set up as an Event. How can we connect Event registration payments (like tickets bought and such) to Contribution totals?

Payments for Events are a Contribution. Perhaps you can confirm that yourself and then finesse the question.
